# How to configure URN

Tags: php, apache, url, soap, urn

I like to learn about below URL.

> https://server_ip/testing/urn:id:value

I have understand from "https://server_ip/testing/" contains the protocol HTTPS and server ip and path.

I want to know the remaining part of the url **"urn:id:value"**.
How the URL is working without file name and extension.
Whats need to do in server side to provide this type of URL.

I'm using appache V2.4.12 and php V5.5.10.

I got some knowledge from stackoverflow to create the URL without file extension.

> https://server_ip/testing/sample_code.php

to

> https://server_ip/testing/sample_code

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path component is not `/testing/`, but `/testing/urn:id:value`.

While the path segment `urn:id:value` looks like a URN, it isn’t one in this context. It’s a HTTPS URL that probably gives some information about the URN, similar to a HTTPS URL like

```
https://example.com/page-check/http://stackoverflow.com/
```

which might give information about the HTTP URL `http://stackoverflow.com/` (the path is `/page-check/http://stackoverflow.com/`).

But it’s only for usability reasons that it’s contained in the path like that. The URL could as well be something like

```
https://example.com/page-check?protocol=https&domain=stackoverflow.com&path=/
```

or

```
https://example.com/page-check/f623Dn1
```

Comment: Hi, Can you help me with example. what I need to do in server side. If I open the url in browser with **urn:id:value** .  I'm getting page not found.

Comment: @Rajalakshmi: Well, you have to generate a page for this URL, just like it’s the case with any other page, too: if someone requests `/foo`, you serve a certain document. Nothing different if someone requests `/testing/urn:id:value`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. I have done the configuration in apache as mentioned below. "RewriteEngine On  RewriteRule "/testing/" "/test/index.php"  to get the urn id and value. Is this the correct way. Is this affect any performance?

Comment: Hi Unor, I know this is old.. but isn't `:` a reserved character to delimit the scheme, user/password, and host/port components? is it valid to use it in a URL path like you showed?

Comment: @Rain: Yes, but `:` is only reserved in that components. In the path component, it’s unreserved (see [allowed chars in the path](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/91211/17633)).